# C# Linq Select two tables select MAX date from one

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have two tables:

```
User
-----------------
ID       int
Name     varchar

UserStatus
-----------------
ID          int
UserId      int
Status      varchar
ActiveDate datetime
EndDate    datetime
```

Using Linq in C# how would I get all information from the User table and all the columns from the user status table by the max active date and the end date being null?

I know the following wont work but it is kind of a rudimentary example of what I am trying to do.

```
ctx.Users.Include("UserStatus").Where(s => s.UserStatus.Max(t => t.ActiveDate) & s.UserStatus.EndDate != null).OrderBy(s => s.Name)
```

Thanks

EDIT

Lets say the user table has the following:

```
1     Billy Bob
2     Bilbo baggins
```

and the user status table has:

```
1    1   Active   1/1/2011 null
2    1   Reserved 1/1/2011 3/5/2011
3    2   Active   2/22/2011 null
```

I would like the following results:

```
1   Billy Bob     Active   1/1/2011
2   Bilbo Baggins Active 2/22/2011
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this in two parts. First, group by and set the max value (using the `let` keyword), then compare using that value and finally select your object.

```
var query = (from user in ctx.Users
    join userStatus in ctx.UserStatuses on user.ID equals userStatus.User.ID
    where userStatus.EndDate == null
    group userStatus by new
        {
            userStatus.User.ID,
            userStatus.ActiveDate
        } into userGroup
    let maxActiveDate = userGroup.Max(x => x.ActiveDate)

    from userStatus in userGroup
    where userStatus.ActiveDate == maxActiveDate
    select new
    {
        userStatus.User.ID,
        userStatus.User.Name,
        userStatus.Status,
        userStatus.ActiveDate
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<UserStatus> GetUsers(string name)
{
    var query = (from u in db.User 
                 join us in db.UserStatus on u.ID equals us.ID 
                 where u.Name == name 
                 orderby us.ActiveDate descending
                 select us)
                 as IEnumerable<UserStatus>;
    return query;
}
```

Or, if you only want the single record w/ the MAX ActiveDate, you would keep the same linq statement, but use .First() at the end, and you'd change your return type as well to be only DateTime, etc.

Comment: I added data examples above of what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for every entry that does NOT have an End Date (thus is active), then you could just use

```
Where(x => x.UserStatus.EndDate == null)
```

I don't see the need for the max date in your examples.

Comment: This did not work.  s.UserStatus.EndDate is not a legal call.

Comment: It won't even let me call enddate, it only offers .Where() etc...  not the column names.

Comment: Ignore my example of what I am trying to do, it is gibberish and wont compile. I just provided it as a direction to what I am doing.

Comment: I am thinking groupby and select new need to be involved.

Comment: Still not sure if I understand you correctly, but I modified my answer to reflect what I understood.

Comment: I added data examples above of what I am looking for.

Comment: That would work, but when I intellisense after x.UserStatus. all I get is the Add, Aggregate, All etc... list.  That is why I am thinking groupby has to come into play here.

Comment: Then User.UserStatus is being mapped as a Collection. Are you using EF or Linq2SQL?

Comment: Make sure to set the Multiplicity of your UserStatus association to 0..1 or 1 in your model designer.

Comment: I have it set from User 1 to UserStatus *(Many)

Comment: If one user can have multiple status entries then you will need `GroupBy`

Comment: Look at my sixth comment down in this chain ;)

Comment: Yes, you mentioned it already. I'm afraid I can't help you there... :(

Answer (score 1):

```
ctx.Users.Where(u => u.UserStatus.Max(us => us.ActiveDate) && u.UserStatus.EndDate.HasValue())
    .OrderBy(u => u.Name)
```

that seems like what you want